# cannot resolve hostname error

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy

I have a model B pi with the latest version of wheezy installed.  I cannot connect to the internet at all.  I am using an [edimax nano wifi dongle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CLMJLU) and using the recommended 5.25v power supply.  If i use the `wpa_gui` it comes back with this:

```
status:         completed (station)
last message:   WPS-TIMEOUT requested operation timed out
authentication: NONE
encryption:     WEP-104
SSID:           9N670
BSSID:          correct
```

but the IP address remains blank...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** the incorrect date and time are displayed in the lower right corner

Comment: The data/time is set by connecting to network time servers so without a network the time is not set.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Raspian Wheezy, then most probabaly your OS does not have the required drivers for your dongle. Try updating your OS by connecting it to the internet using Ethernet. Run apt-get update then apt-get upgrade. connect your dongle and try again.If it still doesn't work then the driver is missing.

1. [This is the link to a  similar issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/setting-up-wifi-with-sweex/6696?noredirect=1#comment10133_6696)
2. [Try this link as well for a similar solution](http://pingbin.com/2012/12/setup-wifi-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not supplied lots of debug information, I am going to list diagnoses and possible solutions.

1. **Dongle is not powered properly**

   Please buy a [Powered USB Hub](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/8978659130195106761?q=powered%20usb%20hub&safe=active&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45218183,d.dmQ&biw=1366&bih=667&sa=X&ei=HOxtUZDXM4qx0QGx24CwBQ&ved=0CIkBEPMCMAA). This will help the wifi dongle to properly connect *and stay connected.*
2. **Problem Dongle**

   Several Wifi Dongles are not compatible with the Pi. Find the alpha-numeric code on your dongle, and see if it is in [this list](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Problem_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters). Then, see if it is under the header of "problem" or "works."
3. **Not Configured Properly**

   You may have not configured your files properly. This includes `WLAN` and `WPA.` Please visit [this tutorial](http://pingbin.com/2012/12/setup-wifi-raspberry-pi/) for more information.

If these do not help, please type `ifconfig -a` into the terminal and type the results here. Also, you may be helped by several links about this issue. See [this forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=10071) and [this stackexchange question.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3722/6609)